# Unable to fetch record from mongoDB as per date range using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to fetch records from mongoDB within the date range but as per my code no record is coming. I am explaining my code below.

> ubot-stats::

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("60aa4ac8dbf65f620fd61c35"),
    "cec" : "subhrajp",
    "action" : "Admin",
    "created_date" : ISODate("2021-05-31T06:52:56.000Z"),
    "count" : 12
}
```

The above is my collection and I need to fetch record as per created date.

> app.js::

```
const filter = {'$gte': new Date(req.body.fromDate).toISOString(), '$lte': new Date(req.body.toDate).toISOString()};
console.log('filter', filter);//{'$gte': '2021-05-27T00:00:00.000Z','$lte': '2021-05-31T00:00:00.000Z'}

connObj.collection("ubot-stats").find({created_date:filter}).toArray(function(error, docs) {
          console.log('\nError =>', error);
          console.log('\nDocs =>', docs);
          if (error || !docs) {
            responseObj = {
              status: 'error',
              msg: `Error occurred while fetching docs from "stats" collection present in ${dbName} database`,
              body: error
            };
            client.close();
            res.send(responseObj);
          }else{
            responseObj = {
              status: 'success',
              msg: `successfully fetched the docs`,
              body: docs
            };
            client.close();
            res.send(responseObj);
          }
        })
```

Here I need to fetch record as per created date within `fromDate and toDate` which is mention above but as per this code no recording is coming. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tryed `$gte` withouth quotes? or maybe you'll need to use timestamp format

Comment: let me to try that.

Comment: @UlisesMartínezElías, Actually new date is giving 1 day off date.

Comment: Not shure what is happening. Please update the code and the question

Comment: @UlisesMartínezElías: I updated my code. `{'$gte': '2021-05-27T00:00:00.000Z','$lte': '2021-05-31T00:00:00.000Z'}` this is the date range but record still not coming. When I am changing to `2021-06-01T00:00:00.000Z'`, the record is fetching.

Comment: Are you saving your timestamps as strings? mongoDB can easily work with Date() which work with ISODate format. I would recommend to use ISODate instead of ISOString

Answer (score 0):

With dates I recommend you ther the library [moment](https://momentjs.com/). I always use it to use dates.

Then you could try this filter:

```
const startDate = moment(req.body.fromDate)
const endDate = moment(req.body.toDate)

{ '$and': [
   { 'created_date': { '$gte': startDate} }, 
   { 'created_date': { '$lte': endDate} }
]}
```

Comment: I did as per you but still its not fetching.